# Display the documents with partial matching of field value in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The below is my movie schema:

```
  "_id" : ObjectId("59b9501600fcb397d6acd5bb"),
     "theatreid" : 2,
"name" : "carnival cinemas",
"location" : "kanjulmarg",
  "address" : "sec 2,kanjul, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400703",
"shows" : [
  {
          "mname" : "bareily ki barfi",
          "timings" : [
                  10,
                  13,
                  14,
                  16,
                  22
          ]
  },

  {
          "mname" : "Toilet:ek prem katha",
          "timings" : [
                  8,
                  9,
                  14,
                  16,
                  20,
                  23
          ]
  }
 ]


 "_id" : ObjectId("59b9506500fcb397d6acd5bc"),
   "theatreid" : 3,
 "name" : "pheonix pvr",
 "location" : "kurla",
 "address" : "sec 26,kurla, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400701",
"shows" : [
  {
          "mname" : "shubh mangal savdhan",
          "timings" : [
                  9,
                  11,
                  15,
                  18,
                  20
          ]
      },
  {
          "mname" : "Toilet:ek prem katha",
          "timings" : [
                  8,
                  9,
                  14,
                  16,
                  20,
                  23
          ]
  }
]
```

My query is to display all the theaters having show timing (shows.timings) greater than 20 and the location is kurla.**I am using nodeJS.**
The query is as follows:

```
 user.aggregate([{$match:{"location":"kurla"}},{"$addFields": {"shows": {"$map": {"input": "$shows","as": "resultm","in": {"name": "$$resultm.name","mname": "$$resultm.mname","timings": {"$filter": {"input": "$$resultm.timings","as": "resultf","cond": {"$gte": ["$$resultf",10]}}}}}}}}])
```

This works fine when it gets the exact match where **location="kurla"**,but i want that it should also work and display the same records even if **location=kurla east,maharashthra,mumbai**.That is even if a partial match is found in the location attribute of my collection.How can this be done!Please help. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$regex` operator to apply a partial text match on the `location` attribute.

Replace this ...

```
{$match:{"location":"kurla"}}
```

... with this:

```
{ $match: {location: { $regex: /^kurla/ } } }
```

In the above example the condition is `location like 'kurla%'`.

More details [in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).

This presumes that the values you wish to filter on are all in the `location` field, this is consistent with the following statement from your question:

> location=kurla east,maharashthra,mumbai

There are no examples of "maharashthra" or "mumbai" in the `location` field in the example documents you showed however "maharashthra" does appear in the `address` attribute so if your filter is actually to be applied to `location` and/or `address` then the solution will be different to what I have posted above. If this is the case, perhaps you could update your question to clarify.

Comment: Ya you pointed out right.My location field simply contains the name i.e "kurla",but still i want to show the same result even if the user enters kurla east,maharashtra,mumbai.What change needs to be done.I tried using the above query which u gave,but is not working.Please help !

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your requirements. I _think_ you might be saying something like: `whatever value the user enters should be evaluated against either location or address to see if there is a partial match`. Is that the intention here? It would be easier to understand this if you supplied (a) some cutdown documents (just focussing on the fields which are relevant to this question) and (b) some sample queries in psuedo code and (c) the desired end result (expressed in the form of cutdown documents) for each of the sample queries.

Comment: Thanks @glitch !.I figured it out,using the split function applied on the user's entered string and then manipulated according to my requirements.Thanks for the help though!